# Echo PHP to HTML table

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

Having issues with this PHP echo while loop. What am I doing wrong? Page won't load due to it.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `uploads`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) //while loop
{
$id = $row['id']; //get ID
$name = $row['name']; //get name
//variable for getting name and ID
```

// echo out all songs and display with name.

```
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>Name</td>";
 echo "<td><a href='listen.php?id=$id' target='_new' >$name </a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: each <td> needs its own <tr> tag

Comment: maybe your stuck in a while loop which is infinite ? Please show us the loop

Comment: @Akin You can have multiple `<td>` inside one row `<tr>`

Comment: @Akin is wrong, <td>s are Elements in <tr>s and don't need their own <tr> each

Comment: Please, share the full code, including the PHP part

Comment: show full code, i think stuck in while loop.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code you posted. _Why do you think so?_

Comment: Enable error-reporting, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: have you closed the whileloop

Comment: Full code added

Comment: please consider reading [THIS : about quotes/backticks...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql) and as  mysql_* was deprecated in PHP 5.5 (please refer to [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)) you should prefer [PPS : Prepared Parameterized Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). This will help  [Preventing SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate your `HTML` from `PHP` for easy debugging and your code will be a lot cleaner

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='listen.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' target='_new' ><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you are attempting to link to an $id and $name, one can only assume, from a mysqli_query function which you have omitted.

However, I can see what you are attempting. Firstly, you need not specify echo on every line. Applying this to a snippet of your code changing

```
<?php
 echo "<table>";
 echo "<tr>";
?>
```

to

```
<?php
 echo "<table>
        <tr>";
?>
```

will produce the same result and save some typing.

This is what you are looking for.

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `uploads`";
 $qry = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));


 $table_content = "";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];

      $table_content .= "<tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td><a href='listen.php?id=$id' target='_new'>$name</a></td>
                         </tr>";
    }

   echo "<table>".$table_content."</table>";
 ?>
```

This will produce a table with 2 columns, the first having the value 'Name' for each column, the second a link to the record ID with the records name as the text.

If you are after a table heading called 'Name' you will need to a row with

```
<th>Name</th>
```

Here I use [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) as mysql_query is deprecated. [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) is useful to include when querying your database. In the event the connection fails to execute the query it will provide a (not always useful) error, but atleast point you towads a solution.

Comment: This allowed the page to load unlike my code. However, it does now show any links or table.

Comment: Have you set the mysqli_connect details correctly? I have edited my code to include generic details which you should substitute for your connection details.

Comment: Yes I added in my connection details but the other php on the page seems to conflict with it. I removed the other code and it WORKS! Thank you :)

Comment: Ah great stuff! You are welcome, I'm a new user so would very much appreciate a thumbs up for this solution :).

Comment: You are a life saver! I gave you the thumbs up but as I am new to this also it says since I am less than 15 reputation it has been recorded but won't show publicly